# What will be the sql code for - rows that have NULLs in 'multiple columns'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say for example there are 4 columns and we only want rows to be displayed where more than 1 column has Null value

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENsoB.png)

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output as text, not as a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward (since you're going to have to scan the entire table anyway) is to not try to do anything clever that takes advantage of certain columns being in a specific data type and just add up how many values in each row are null:

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4,
    NumberOfNulls = 0 + 
      CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
      CASE WHEN col2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
      CASE WHEN col3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
      CASE WHEN col4 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  FROM dbo.table_name
)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
WHERE NumberOfNulls > 1;
```

I made up the table and column names here; I didn't look at your screenshot because [please don't post screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/61305).

Comment: thank you so much for the solution, this is my first post so will definitely not use ss in my future posts